# How JVM determines instance when using intrinsic lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm-hotspot

Example:

```
Object lock = createLock();
synchronized (lock) {
    //some statements
}
```

I have some `lock` instance, but don't know is it singleton instance for all application or only local, for this method?

How can I determine this, without finding the place where this object created and how JVM determines this for different threads?

Comment: Are you taking about biased locking? If not, can you explain what you mean by "intrinsic lock"?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm talking about just simple synchronization built on internal entity we can call it monitor lock. Biased locking it's about optimization I think.

Comment: What do you mean by "internal entity"? Aall object are internal to the jvm.

Comment: @PeterLawrey https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html "Internal" mean just internal object which we use in synchronized statements

Answer (score 0):

You can **only** determine the scope of the lock by inspection of the code it comes from. The JVM does not need to determine anything about the object, it merely does what it is told and uses the provided object as the lock token. If it is not a singleton then the locking mechanism fails.

Comment: And how I told this to JVM? Is it inspecting code? And going to place where object created, when we use synchronized statement?

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin - No - it will never inspect the code. If the code does not lock on the same object consistently (i.e. use a singleton) then the locking mechanism will fail and threads will be allowed uncontrolled access. This is why locking is so complex - you have to be **certain** that the object you use to lock with is always the same object.

Comment: I know that JVM knows which object it has in synchronized statement :-) Question is how it know it.

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin - It maintains some state in the `Object`. All Java objects inherit from `Object` and are therefore lockable (using `wait` and `notify`).

Comment: Are you seen some fields in `Object` class that can mantain some state of instance of `Object` class?

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin - As you can see from [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/Object.java#Object.wait%28long%29) the `wait` method is a `native` method so it is probably implemented in C or assembler.

Comment: Yes it's native and we can see source of it's methods in OpenJDK repository http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin It's part of the object header. There are some optimizations but basically there's a reference to an additional data structure in the object header that contains things like the lock count and thread id.

Comment: _If it is not a singleton then the locking mechanism fails_  Say what?  I've written lots of methods that lock a non-singleton object.  What matters is that two different threads that want to operate on the same _data_ should always lock the same lock.  But if N different threads are all in the same method, each working on _different_ data, then there's nothing wrong with having each of them lock a different lock.  In fact, it's often a good idea.

Comment: @jameslarge That's exactly what @OldCurmudgeon had in mind. Statement like `synchronised(new Object()) { }` is useless because every time you lock on a new object.

Answer (score 0):

> docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/… "Internal" mean just internal object which we use in synchronized statements

This is talking about the lock built in to the header of every object.  If you have an Object instance, you have one of these locks.

Primitives don't have such a lock.

[java.util.concurrent.Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) has a non-intrinsic lock, though confusingly it has an intrinsic on as wel..

Comment: You talking about "header of every object", can I get information from this header in my code(with Reflection maybe) or only JVM can do it?

Comment: You can extract information using sun.misc.Unsafe but this is highly unlikely to be a good idea. Can you say what information you are trying to extract and why, as there is likely to be a better way to do what you want?

Comment: I want to check, is some object in synchronized statement unique for different threads without inspecting code, but only with writing code. I need it because I want to check this information without inspecting other developers code. It's not for production using, it's only interesting thing for me.

Comment: The object doesn't record where it could be accessed or has been accessed. In fact there is no way to know without inspecting all teh code loaded.  The object will only record whether baised locking is being used or not.

Comment: @PeterLawery I don't asking about records which contain information about accessing to object. You wrote about some object headers, I asking, may I look at these headers from code.

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin I wrote that "You can extract information using sun.misc.Unsafe but this is highly unlikely to be a good idea. "  And it won't help you achieve your objective.

Answer (score 0):

The variable, lock, in your example is just that:  It's a variable.

A `synchronized` statement locks the lock of the object that it's given.  In your example, it locks the object to which your `lock` variable refers.

So, does your `lock` variable refer to a singleton?  Is it a local variable?  Is it an instance variable in some class?  We can't answer those questions because you haven't shown us the code.

Comment: @jameslargeI I know how determine this in my code. Question is about how JVM determines it and can we usage this method without inspecting place in code where this object created.

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin, The JVM _doesn't_ determine it.  The JVM doesn't care.  All the JVM does is prevent more than one thread from synchronizing the same object at the same time.  It's up to _you_ to make sure that you are synchronizing on the _right_ object  (I.e., to insure that all of the threads and all of the methods that want to operate on the same _data_ will do so while synchronized on the same object).

Comment: How JVM does prevent it? Do you know this mechanism? This is the question.

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin Yes, I know how it works, but it's not something I can explain in a 600 character comment.  Most JVMs use _native threads_ (i.e., operating system threads) to implement Java threads and, use a combination of special hardware instructions (e.g., CMPXCHG on x86-like processors) and native synchronization objects to implement Java synchronization.  So really, your question is a question about how operating systems implement multi-threading.  That's a book-level topic.  The heart of it, and what you want to search for to learn more, is the OS _scheduling algorithm_.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try to search in this direction.